# Animate view moving up on launch

Tags: ios, uiview, uiviewcontroller, autolayout, uiviewanimation

I have a `UIImageView` which is centred horizontally and vertically in the launch screen. I want to display the same logo on the main storyboard (main view controller) when the launch screen goes, centred horizontally but at the top of the screen.

I have added the same image view to my main storyboard in the same position and added the following code to animate the image from centre to top of screen.

```
@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self animateLogo];
}

- (void)animateLogo {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^(void){
        CGRect currentFrame = self.logoView.frame;
        self.logoView.frame = CGRectMake(currentFrame.origin.x, self.view.frame.size.height, currentFrame.size.width, currentFrame.size.height);
    }];
}

@end
```

However instead of seeing the animation move up, I see it move down from the top to centre.

Can someone point me in the right direction to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should animate constraint instead frame:

```
- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    self.topConstraint.constant = (self.view.frame.size.height - self.viewToAnimate.frame.size.height) / 2;
    [self.viewToAnimate setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
    [UIView animateWithDuration:.5 animations:^{
        [self.viewToAnimate layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Tried that and now it animates from the bottom to the centre. I need to animate away from the centre.

Comment: @clicky are both image centered with constraints?

Comment: Yes, centre x and y axis on the launch screen and same on main storyboard vc.

Comment: @clicky you should set constraint constant property instead setting frame. Find this constraint in IB (top constraint - top space to superview), make an outlet for it and in code do yourConstraint.constant = 0

Comment: how do i set a top constraint to initially centre image on y axis?

Comment: @clicky You should connect to outlet you Y constraint. And look at my updated answer again please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70932/discussion-between-clicky-and-marat-al).